# Semi password protected Zip files in Java

Tags: java, zip, zip4j

I need to create a zip file by using Java. Library is not important, but zip4j seems to be a good one. In this zip file, only some of the files or subdirectories will be password protected. For example in the following zip file, only the files starting with "*" will be password protected:

```
foo.zip
 foo1.txt
 *secure
  *secure1.txt
  *secure2.txt
```

Is there any way to implement this scenario in Java?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

this mavne dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

code:

```java
            ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
            parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
            parameters.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.ZIP_STANDARD);
            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(destFile, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            zip.setCharset(InternalZipConstants.CHARSET_UTF_8);

            for (File file : srcFiles) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    zip.addFile(file, parameters);
                } else {
                    zip.addFolder(file, parameters);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found it by using zip4j. Fwollowing snippets can be used for creating both password protected and non-password protected files.

For the files to be password protected:

```
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFileName);

        ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
        zipParameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
        zipParameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
        zipParameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
        zipParameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
        zipParameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);
        zipParameters.setPassword(password);

        zipFile.addFiles(new ArrayList<>(filesToZip), zipParameters);
```

And the files that are not password protected:

```
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFileName);

        ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
        zipParameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
        zipParameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

        zipFile.addFiles(new ArrayList<>(filesToZip), zipParameters);
```